# Warnings in local functions of anonymous functions

Tags: function, delphi, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe

What is the cause of (apparently) spurious warnings when compiling local functions of anonymous functions, and how do I eliminate them.

A simple function compiles clean - no warnings. If the function is a local function of another function, again there are no warnings. If the function is a local function of an anonymous function it gives rise to the following warnings:

```
[DCC Warning] Unit1.pas(57): W1036 Variable 'i' might not have been initialized
[DCC Warning] Unit1.pas(58): W1035 Return value of function 'StrToJType' might be undefined
```

Example code is set out below. Please note that though this code compiles, it gives warnings unrelated to this question because it is incomplete.

**EDIT**
Comments and responses suggest that the fact that the example code contains no return value in the anonymous function may be the cause of the problem. This edit amends the code to remedy this, to simplify the local function case, and to minimise the code. The problem is still the same.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  JType = (JAtLeastOnce, JConditionLine, JInfix, JIteration, JNonNullInfix );
  TFuncTest = reference to function : JType;
  function StrToJType(aString : string) : JType;

implementation

function StrToJType(aString : string) : JType;
// Basic function - does not give warnings
var
  i : integer;
begin
  i := Pos(aString, '+i*-?');
  if i <> 0 then result := JType(i - 1) else result := High(JType);
end;

function Test : JType;
// Local function - does not give warnings
  function StrToJType(aString : string) : JType;
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    i := Pos(aString, '+i*-?');
    if i <> 0 then result := JType(i - 1) else result := High(JType);
  end;
begin
  result := low(JType);
end;

function Test2 : TFuncTest;
// Local function of anonymous function - gives warnings
begin
  result :=
    function : JType
      function StrToJType(aString : string) : JType;
      var
        i : integer;
      begin
        i := Pos(aString, '+i*-?');
        if i <> 0 then result := JType(i - 1) else result := High(JType);
      end;
    begin
      result := Low(JType);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Is it complaining about StrToJType or the anonymous function? Could it be confused about the two since the anonymous function does not set result?

Comment: Regarding your edit, are you surprised? Have you made a minimal reproduction yet? Once you do that, submit it to QP as I advise in my answer.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I believe some of these features were added in D2010, so there may still be weird bugs by the time XE came out. Also, why make an example with extraneous code in it? ie, the local function in the first anonymous method Test that's never referenced. Just curious.

Comment: The local function in Test was intended to be my attempt at minimal code - there were no warnings for the basic function whether referenced or not; none when used as a local function, whether referenced or not); but did emit warnings when used as a local function to an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous function does not assign its return value.

```
function Test2 : TFuncTest;
// Local function of anonymous function - gives warnings
begin
  result :=
    function : JStructureType
      function StrToJType(aString : string) : JStructureType;
      const
        c : string = '+i*-?p!qoxsc<^>8|';
      var
        i : integer;
      begin
        i := Pos(aString, c);
        if (aString <> '') and (i <> 0) then result := JStructureType(i - 1)
        else result := High(JStructureType);
      end;
    begin
      // need to return something here
    end;
end;
```

The compiler should also object to you making the same mistake in `Test`.

If the compiler really is complaining about `StrToJType` after you've fixed all the other errors, that would be a compiler bug and should be submitted to Quality Portal.

**Update**

Your edit confirms that the warnings in the local function remain when you resolve the other mistakes. So this would appear to be a compiler bug. Please make a minimal reproduction and submit it.

Of course Delphi XE won't be updated in the future. Unless this bug still exists in XE8 there's probably no point in reporting a bug.

One might suspect that the compiler is confused by a local function, local to an anonymous method, that is never called

Comment: FWIW, his current code (as of Sun, Jul 26 2015, 3:30 GMT+2) compiles fine in XE8. So he might report it for XE, but I doubt it will ever be fixed for XE.

Comment: Attempted to report it, without success. As it now appears fixed, and I am contemplating upgrading in the near future, I will not action this any further.